# how to get value of wysiwyg custom field (ACF) for product category on wordpress custom page

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wysiwyg

I am creating a custom page to list all the product (taxonomy=product_cat) sub-categories with the ACF fields i have created.

I tried googling for solutions but all i can get is the_field('<>');

but when I am calling this it is not showing any value from the custom fields is WYSIWYG

```
<?php 
$parentid = get_queried_object_id();         
$args = array(
    'parent' => 68,
     'hierarchical' => 1,
     'show_option_none' => '',
     'hide_empty' => 0,
);
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

if ( $terms ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
               var_dump($term);
               echo '<div class="row expand-blocks"><div class="col-md-3">
               <h3 class="category_name">'.$term->name.'</h3>';
               woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail( $term );
               echo'</div> <div class="col-md-9 category_description"><p class="readmoretoggle">'.$term->description.'</p> <div class="row category_full_description"><div class="">';
echo '<div class="col-md-6"><div class="nutrition_value ">';

                    //need to show below                    
                      the_field('nutrition_value_per_one_cup', '107');

                    echo '</div></div> <div class="col-md-6"><div class="useful_value ">';

                    //need to show below
                     the_field('useful_for_body_parts');

                    echo '</div> </div>';

    }


}

?>
```

I expect the html output for the fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reference on this page.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

```
//where $term = term object you get in foreach loop
the_field('nutrition_value_per_one_cup', $term);// display the value itself
or
echo get_field('nutrition_value_per_one_cup', $term);// need to echo or print the value.
```

Answer (score 0):

`the_field('field_name')` is the correct way to display an acf field in your theme according to the [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/).

In your code I see two usage of the function :

```
the_field('nutrition_value_per_one_cup', '107');

the_field('useful_for_body_parts');
```

Which one isn't right ?
What is the current output you get?

Also why do you force the prost_id value to `107` on the first one as you are in a loop?

Do you try to force the post_id of the term?:

```
the_field('your_field_name', $term->id);
```

It may be $term->ID, I'm not sure.

Comment: Both are right format here i need to make it as conditional so that i can retrieve its value based on 

the_field('useful_for_body_parts', $term->term_id);

My Current condition is taxonomy=product_cat

and i am trying to display it on custom page template